# How with collections to use map and filter methods in one opearator?

Tags: laravel

Working with collections in Laravel 6 is there is a way to use map and filter methods in one opearator?

I tried like :

```
$dataItems = ItemModel
    ::getById($id)
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($item) {
        $item['field1']  = 'value1';
        $item['field2']  = 'value2';
        ...
        
        if($conditionTrue) {
            return $item;
        }
        return false;
    })
    ->toArray();
```

But when $conditionTrue was false I got empty elements in result array.

Can I do it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really for some reason don't want to just call `filter()`, which will remove any items equivalent to `false`, after your call to `map(...)` you can take the callback you have an use it with `filter` instead, since the items are objects:

```
->filter(function ($item) {
    $item['field1']  = 'value1';
    $item['field2']  = 'value2';
    ...

    return $condition;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `reduce` method instead:

```
// where $acc is the accumulated value and $curr is the current value in the loop
->reduce(function($acc, $curr) {
    $curr['field1']  = 'value1';
    $curr['field2']  = 'value2';

    if($conditionTrue) {
        $acc[] = $curr;
    }

    return $acc;
}, array());
```

i think the reduce method is what you were looking for. this method alone does the job for both map and filter.

make sure not to call toArray(), because reduce will return an array